# flatpak keeps hopping between install and remove on subsequent `flatpak update` runs

Tags: package-managers, flatpak

When I run `flatpak update`, it says that the packages `org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel` and `org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default` are at end of life and removes them. However, on its next run, it installs them again, and then removes them on its next run again and so on.

Here's the output from my last 2 runs.

```
agamagarwal@glados:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…
Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version
Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version


        ID                                            Branch          Op
 1. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default           19.08           r
 2. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel          19.08           r

Uninstall complete.
agamagarwal@glados:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…
Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version
Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
   The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version


        ID                                              Branch            Op           Remote            Download
 1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default             19.08             i            flathub           88.6 MB / 89.1 MB
 2. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel            19.08             i            flathub            8.6 MB / 8.7 MB

Installation complete.
```

As mentioned, this keeps repeating on subsequent `flatpak update` runs.

I am running `Pop!_OS 21.04 x86_64` and flatpak version `1.11.2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flatpak uninstall --unused` fixed it.
It removed those end-of-life packages for good.
Now running `flatpak update` doesn't do this.